# predicting the index number based on spiral data

Tags: r, computer-science, data-manipulation

[image]

Each co-ordinate(x,y) corresponds to an index. For example: (0,0) has index 0   AND (1,0) has index 1 .

```
 X <-c(0,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,2,2,2,1,0,-1,-2)
 Y <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,2,2,2,2)
 Z<- as.factor(0:16)
 df <- data.frame(X,Y,Z)
 library(e1071)
 model <- svm(Z ~ X+Y, xyz, kernel = "radial")
 predict(model, xyz[1:4,1:2]) #1.647681 3.859354 5.908940 4.151374 
# From the last code, it appears that it does not predict well for its own data
```

## i need help in building a predictive model which can predict the index.

What is the index corresponding to (12,-22) ?